# Using setter methods as defensive link (relationship) management methods in JPA

Tags: hibernate, jpa, orm, eclipselink, jpa-2.1

The inverse side (Department) :

```
public class Department implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "department_id", nullable = false)
    private Long departmentId;

    @Column(name = "department_name", length = 255)
    private String departmentName;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "department", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Employee> employeeList = new ArrayList<Employee>(0);

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Department() {}

    public void add(Employee employee) {
        List<Employee> newEmployeeList = getEmployeeList();

        if (!newEmployeeList.contains(employee)) {
            newEmployeeList.add(employee);
        }

        if (employee.getDepartment() != this) {
            employee.setDepartment(this);
        }
    }

    public void remove(Employee employee) {
        List<Employee> newEmployeeList = getEmployeeList();

        if (newEmployeeList.contains(employee)) {
            newEmployeeList.remove(employee);
        }

        employee.setDepartment(null);
    }

    // Remaining getters + setters + hashcode() + equals() + toString().
}
```

The owning side (Employee) :

```
public class Employee implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "employee_id", nullable = false)
    private Long employeeId;

    @Column(name = "employee_name", length = 255)
    private String employeeName;

    @JoinColumn(name = "department_id", referencedColumnName = "department_id")
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.DETACH})
    private Department department;

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public void setDepartment(Department department) {
        this.department = department;

        if (department != null) {
            List<Employee> employeeList = department.getEmployeeList();

            if (!employeeList.contains(this)) {
                employeeList.add(this);
            }
        }
    }

    // Remaining getters + setters + hashcode() + equals() + toString().
}
```

As can be seen, the setter method `setDepartment()` in the `Employee` entity is assigned an additional responsibility for brevity in application code - made to do the link management task. It adds `Department` to a list of employees on the inverse side on its own.

On the inverse side, there are also two relationship management methods namely, `add()` and `remove()`. If setters are assigned this kind of link management tasks, then one does not have to explicitly remember adding an entity to the other side of a relationship. Otherwise, one has to remember explicitly calling the `add()` method in `Department` whenever necessary.

► Does assigning this task to setter methods cause some side effects especially when access type is set to property (`@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)`)?

Somewhat resemblance to this is seriously warned against by [the JPA WikiBook](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Print_version#Odd_behavior) causing lazily initialized relationships to be always inadvertently initialized eagerly, when access type is set to property.

> There are many reasons that odd behavior can occur with persistence.
>   One common issue that can cause odd behavior is using property access
>   and putting side effects in your get or set methods. For this reason
>   it is generally recommended to use field access in mapping, i.e.
>   putting your annotations on your variables not your get methods.
>
> For example consider :
>
> ```
> public void setPhones(List<Phone> phones) {
>     for (Phone phone : phones) {
>         phone.setOwner(this);
>     }
>     this.phones = phones;
> }
> ```
>
> **This may look innocent, but these side effects can have unexpected
>   consequences. For example if the relationship was lazy this would have
>   the effect of always instantiating the collection when set from the
>   database.** It could also have consequences with certain JPA
>   implementations for persisting, merging and other operations, causing
>   duplicate inserts, missed updates, or a corrupt object model.
>
> I have also seen simply incorrect property methods, such as a get method 
>   that always returns a new object, or a copy, or set methods that don't
>   actually set the value.
>
> In general if you are going to use property
>   access, ensure your property methods are free of side effects. Perhaps
>   even use different property methods than your application uses.

Comment: Not sure I understand the question.  If JPA is set to use these methods to set your fields, it is bad as these methods affect the entity passed in in ways that will cause problems when it must merge, load and persist your model.  If JPA isn't configured to use these methods, then it doesn't matter - they are just methods invisible to JPA and the warning doesn't apply.  You will be modifying both entities, so it doesn't mater if you do it in a setter convenience method or somewhere else in the code